# Predict multiple, potentially overlapping categories?

Tags: ranking, multinomial-logit, many-categories

I have a training dataset that consists of movies that have category labels.  There can be more than one label assigned to a movie.  For example:

- Movie: Finding Nemo; Labels: children, animation
- Movie: Beauty and the Beast; Labels: children, fairytale, animation
- Movie: Ella Enchanted; Labels: fairytale, live action

I want to build a model to predict labels for movies that I don't already have them for, based on a dataset of other features--not really important to the question which ones.  At first I thought about using something like logistic regression with multiple classes.  But, I want to allow for the possibility of more than one label being assigned.

I guess I could build a model for each label, that predicts the probability that the given label describes a movie, and then choose a cutoff threshold on the probability for deciding to make the assignment.

Can someone give me ideas about a better approach?  Models that are built to handle this problem?

Comment: I do not have much experience in this area, but I could imagine the multi-class logistic approach working OK perhaps. So for output you have a softmax, right? So just as in binary logistic, the cutoff used to "harden" the soft classification is an additional parameter (e.g. where people do ROC curves, etc.). So the output could be consistent w/multi-labels. On the training-data side, you could use single labels, but add *copies* of the data that are multi-label (one for each label). Not sure how this compares with your suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, I think that this is consistent with what I was thinking of doing.  The only thing I worry about is that there are ~40 categories, so it's a lot of models to train.  That's ok, but the list of categories can also get bigger in the future, so that means every time the list updates I have to add another model in.  I was just hoping to find an approach that is more...elegant?  Maybe something like a ranking model could work too?

Comment: Training a separate logistic regression model for each label is no less elegant than training a single multi-class logistic model. In the multi-class case, you train a separate linear model for each label, all with their own set of parameters, and simply normalize them by using a Softmax activation to impose the constraint that the probabilities sum to one. In the separate binary case you're also training a separate linear model for each label, but imposing no such constraint. That's *better*, because there should be no constraint on the sum of probabilities in reality.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but I'm not comparing this approach to multi-class LR, as I don't think that model is appropriate for my case.  As far as I know in multi-class LR the classes should be completely distinct.  What I'm wondering is if there is a model that is built for this kind of scenario, where instead of classifying I want to associate any number of appropriate labels with a sample.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing as described in the question, training a separate binomial logistic regression model for each category label.  The steps were as follows:

1. For category 'A', split labeled (training) data into 'A' and 'not A'.
2. Train the LR model.
3. Find the outcome probability of the model that corresponds to an acceptable threshold on a classification metric (in this case the balanced accuracy).
4. Make predictions for unlabeled data (data that was not in the training set).
5. Based on the result of step (3), assign label 'A', or don't, to the unlabeled data points.

This was repeated for all categories.  The system is working acceptably.  I still feel like there may be a better approach out there, but everyone I've talked to has seemed to think this one is fine!